# Continuous maps between orthogonal groups

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, topological-groups, orthogonal-matrices

For a natural number $n$, do we have a continuous map from the orthogonal group $O(n)$ to the orthogonal group $O(n+1)$ (seen as topological spaces)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is continuous inclusion map: Let $O(n)$ act on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, by ignoring the $(n+1)-$th component and acting on the first $n$ components in the usual way.